# javascript object filter using user_id not return expect result

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, multidimensional-array, filter

I have below object

```
var total_hours = <?php echo json_encode($total_hours); ?>;



    [
      {"user_id": 2959
       "total_hours": "38"
      }
      {"user_id": 116
       "total_hours": "1"
      }
    ]
```

i want to get **total_hours** base on **user_id**

```
var user = document.getElementById("user").value;

            var yahooOnly = total_hours.filter(function (entry) {
                return entry.user_id === user;
            });

            total_hours = yahooOnly;
```

but um unable to get required output. Can someone helps me?

Try this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object) but didn't get required output!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filter()` returns an array. You need to index it and then access the `total_hours` property.

You can use `.find()` instead of `.filter()` to get the object instead of an array.

```js
var total_hours = [{
  "user_id": 2959,
  "total_hours": "38"
}, {
  "user_id": 116,
  "total_hours": "1"
}];

var user = 2959;
var yahooOnly = total_hours.find(entry => entry.user_id == user);
var yahoo_hours = yahooOnly.total_hours;
console.log(yahoo_hours)
```